# Apache serves cached content when using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite

Additional information: the webserver is running on a free shared hosting, it also uses cloudflare.

I wanted to use query strings as this:

> https://websitename/share/result/parameter

Instead of this:

> https://websitename/share.php?result=parameter

Where parameter is the query string value.

I managed to do it by modifying the .htaccess file which looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ share.php?result=$1
</IfModule>
```

When i update the content of the ***share.php*** file it serves the new content if i access it by navigating to:

> https://websitename/share

But when i try to access it by:

> https://websitename/share/ *or by* https://websitename/share/parameter

It simply serves the cached version of the ***share.php*** file. What can i do about this problem?

**Things i tried so far:**

- Purged cache on cloudflare
- Set caching level to: no query string
- Deleted browser cache
- Tried to open website in a different browser

Comment: Are you sure the server serves that? Did you try clearing the browsers cache? Test additionally with wget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to solve the problem.**

The solution was changing the htaccess from this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ share.php?result=$1
</IfModule>
```

To this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^share/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /share?result=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```